Weird Browser Problem
The following is new behavior.  It happens in Chrome (under Windows) but not in Firefox:
At the top of my screen, there are various buttons for accessing my inbox, my reputation, the various tools, a list of communities, etc.  Normally I click on a button and a small popup window appears, from which I can navigate further.
What's happening now is that the little popup window briefly appears and then quickly vanishes before I have a chance to click on anything.  So for example, if I want to read my inbox, I click on the inbox icon, am given a (very) brief glimpse of what's in my inbox, and then it's suddenly too late to click on any of the individual messages.
I'm not sure whether this is a problem at my end or something going on with  StackExchange.  (The same problem occurs in math.stackexchange.  It does not occur in MathOverflow.)  I am posting mostly to ask if others are having the same issue.
PS: The same thing happens when I try to choose tags for this post.  I click into the "Tags" box, I am shown some tags I can choose, and the selection disappears before I can choose anything.  I finally managed, after several tries, to click on "discussion" in the instant before it disappeared.  I'd like to add "bug", but I'm apparently not quick enough.

It's not happening on my end

It works fine for me on the latest Microsoft Edge (v128).

Not happening for me, I'm on Windows using Chrome Version 128.0.6613.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Just updated to Chrome Version 128.0.6613.120 (Official Build) (64-bit) and still not having any issues. Do you have an ad blocker turned on? That might mess with the popups. If so, you could try disabling the ad blocker for this site.

@hft :  great suggestion but all ad blockers are off and the problem persists.

We did some investigation on this but were unable to reproduce it.
